# Type hint for Scikit-learn predictor

Tags: python, python-3.x, scikit-learn, strong-typing, python-typing

Is `BaseEnsemble` the correct superclass/interface for Scikit-learn predictors? I am new to Python, so maybe I am not thinking about the problem in the right way. If this were Java, this would be `public class RandomForestClassifier implements Classifiable` (or something) and my method would be `public Classifiable train_from_db()`.

I have a function that prepares and returns a `RandomForestClassifier`:

```
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.ensemble import BaseEnsemble
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score

def train_from_db():
    X = []
    y = []
    for sample_features, sample_class in query_local_database():
        X.append(sample_features)
        y.append(sample_class)
    clf = RandomForestClassifier(random_state=0)
    clf.fit(X, y)
    return clf
```

I added type hints to the function to make it easier to use elsewhere in my program. I started out with:

```
def train_from_db() -> RandomForestClassifier:
```

This works. I generalize with:

```
def train_from_db() -> BaseEnsemble:
```

My program still runs, but was this a good way to go?

Comment: Can you clarify what you are asking? "was this a good way to go?" depends entirely on what you are trying to achieve. Note that type hints are not automatically used by Python at runtime at all, so "My program still runs" says nothing about whether your annotations are correct or not.

Comment: I did not know that Python does not automatically check type hints. You're right, I changed it to `return False` and do not get any warnings until runtime. I probably have the wrong mental model for strong typing in Python.

Comment: You must use a type checker such as ``mypy`` or an IDE to verify types. There are only some explicitly opt-in features that use types as runtime, e.g. ``functools.singledispatch``.